# Can't see bootable Windows 10 USB on one-time boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb, windows-10

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my DELL Inspiron 5570 PC. Previously I had Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 dual boot and then I removed Windows 10. But I can still see Windows Boot Manager on one-time boot menu.

Now I am trying to again install Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 20.04. Secure boot option is disabled. Here is the steps I followed.

- Create an Ubuntu 20.04 bootable USB.
- Turn on the PC with Ubuntu 20.04 USB and shorten the size of main Ubuntu 20.04 installation by 40 GBs.
- Turn on the actual Ubuntu 20.04.
- Partition the USB again with msdos partition table and NTFS file system.
- Download Win 10 ISO file.
- Open the ISO file with Disk Image Mounter and copy all the files inside USB.
- Reboot the PC to install Win 10.

In this step, I can not see boot with Win 10 USB option on one-time boot menu. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you can use a tool to create the Windows installer in the USB drive. That way it is more likely that you really get it working. See [this link (mkusb)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) and [this link (Windows installer)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive) and links from it: mkusb-tow 'to Windows' can be called from mkusb-dus (version 12) and from mkusb-plug.

Comment: @sudodus mkusb worked, thank you. Now I get `device drivers not found` error. Somehow windows installation can not see my 40 GBs of free disk.

Comment: Generally it is easier to first install Windows, and then install Ubuntu. But it should work the way you do it too. -- I think you can get better help with Windows and its drivers, if you ask at a forum for Windows (because the people who answer the questions here focus on Ubuntu). Maybe you should change some setting in the BIOS/UEFI menus (I am only guessing).